# Highlight Row based on time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have table in html, I want to highlight the next event based on the time. Here is the code

```html
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" width="300px">
  <tbody>
    <tr value="05:48">
      <td>
        <center>Fajr</center>
      </td>
      <td>
        <center><i class="wi wi-horizon"></center></td>
        <td><center>5:48</center></td>
      </tr>

     <tr value="07:01">
        <td><center>Sunrise</center></td>
  <td><center><i class="wi wi-sunrise"></center></td>
        <td><center>7:01</center></td>
      </tr>

     <tr value="12:43">
        <td><center>Dhuhr</center></td>
  <td><center><i class="wi wi-day-sunny"></center></td>
        <td><center>12:43</center></td>
      </tr>
        
      <tr value="15:53">
        <td><center>Asr</center></td>
  <td><center><i class="wi wi-horizon-alt"></center></td>
        <td><center>3:53</center></td>
      </tr>
        
       <tr value="18:24">
        <td><center>Magrib</center></td>
  <td><center><i class="wi wi-sunset"></center></td>
        <td><center>6:24</center></td>
      </tr>
      
      <tr value="19:39">
        <td><center>Isha</center></td>
  <td><center><i class="wi wi-moon-full"></center></td>
        <td><center>7:39</center></td>
      </tr>

      </tbody>
  </table>
```

Here is the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/zr1332jk/3/

So if the time is 12:00 it should highlight 12:43.

Comment: OK, so, you know what you want to do, and we assume you've tried some things. What do you need help with? There's not a single question in your "question".

Comment: Agreed, you need to show the code that creates the table, not the rendered output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on this :

> So if the time is 12:00 it should highlight 12:43.

```js
$(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
     var now = new Date();
        var hours = now.getHours();
        console.log(hours);
        $('table tr').each(function(i,v){
         if($(this).attr("value").split(":")[0]==hours)
                $(this).addClass("hightlight");
            else
                $(this).removeClass("hightlight");
        });
    },1000);
});
```

```css
.hightlight{
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <table  cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" width="300px">
    <tbody>
      <tr value="05:48">
        <td><center>Fajr</center></td>
        <td><center><i class="wi wi-horizon"></center></td>
        <td><center>5:48</center></td>
      </tr>

     <tr value="07:01">
        <td><center>Sunrise</center></td>
  <td><center><i class="wi wi-sunrise"></center></td>
        <td><center>7:01</center></td>
      </tr>

     <tr value="12:43">
        <td><center>Dhuhr</center></td>
  <td><center><i class="wi wi-day-sunny"></center></td>
        <td><center>12:43</center></td>
      </tr>
        
      <tr value="15:53">
        <td><center>Asr</center></td>
  <td><center><i class="wi wi-horizon-alt"></center></td>
        <td><center>3:53</center></td>
      </tr>
        
       <tr value="18:24">
        <td><center>Magrib</center></td>
  <td><center><i class="wi wi-sunset"></center></td>
        <td><center>6:24</center></td>
      </tr>
      
      <tr value="19:39">
        <td><center>Isha</center></td>
  <td><center><i class="wi wi-moon-full"></center></td>
        <td><center>7:39</center></td>
      </tr>
          
      <tr value="17:15">
        <td><center>TEST</center></td>
  <td><center><i class="wi wi-moon-full"></center></td>
        <td><center>17:15</center></td>
      </tr>

      </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: Perfect Thank you I could not figure out the part of highlighting a specific row. Your awesome!